# Unexpected double printing of awk when printing unmatching pattern

Tags: awk, printing, grep

I have data organized as lines (no columns). Lines altern between ">name" and "data", such that:

```
>name1
textA
>name2
textB
>name3
textC
```

I want to remove lines with a given name and the associated data - e.g., remove the data for >name3, meaning that both the line >name3 and the textC line should be removed.

I am using:

`awk 'BEGIN {RS = ">"; ORS = ""} !/name3/ {print">"; print $0}' FILE`

However, the output is as following:

```
>>name1
textA
>name2
textB
```

I have tried several alternatives but I did not manage to get the first line right (e.g., either the ">" is doubled or completely missing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The record separator is `>`.
The first character of the file is `>`.
Thus, the first record of the file is the empty string before the first record separator.

You want:

```bash
awk '
  BEGIN {RS = ">"; ORS = ""}
  length && $1 != "name3" {print RS $0}
' file
```

```
>name1
textA
>name2
textB
```

---

An alternate way to solve the problem:

```bash
paste - - < file | grep -v '>name3[[:blank:]]' | tr '\t' '\n'
```

Comment: Thanks! I am not sure I understand the length part. Does length return false if empty?

Comment: awk uses 0 (or the empty string) as false. Anything else is true.

Answer (score 0):

One `awk` idea using a positive match:

```
$ awk '$1 == ">name3" { getline; next }1' file
>name1
textA
>name2
textB
```

Where:

- if 1st column matches on `>name3` (and won't match on `>name33`) then read the next line (`getline`) and then skip to processing for the next line of input; effectively skipping the current and next lines
- any line that does not get caught by the match/`getline` is processed by the standlone `1` (aka `true`, aka print current line to stdout)

Answer (score 0):

If your data row is just one line, this might work

```
$ awk -v var="name3" 'set == 1{set = 0; next}
                      $0 ~ var{set = 1; next}1' file
>name1
textA
>name2
textB
```

If they have more rows, use this instead

```
$ awk -v var="name3" '/>/{set = 0}
                      set == 1{next}
                      $0 ~ var{set = 1; next}1' file2
>name1
textA
>name2
textB
textB
```

##### Data

```
$ cat file2
>name1
textA
>name2
textB
textB
>name3
textC
textC
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also do like this (not beautiful but it works):

```
awk 'BEGIN { RS = "\n>name3\ntextC\n*" } 1' file
```

- `\n` is line-ending for the 4th line.
- `\n` is line-ending for the 5th line.
- `\n*` is line-endings for 6th and above lines.

The catch is that your awk must be able to set a regex for the `RS` variable.

Comment: Probably `RS="(\n>name3\ntextC\n|\n)"` would be better. This will avoid an extra blank line at end of file.

Comment: But then I need to have the ">name3" and "textC" within the command line, which was applicable for the example I gave, but not for the real data ... thanks anyway!

Comment: @Isoldini `awk -v var=">name3" 'BEGIN { RS="(\n" var "\n[^\n]*\n|\n)" } 1' file`.

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
cat file
>name1
textA
>name2
textB
>name3
textC
```

You can use `sed` to delete the match and the line following:

```
sed -e '/^>name2$/,+1d' file 
>name1
textA
>name3
textC
```

With `awk` you can do:

```
awk -v p="^>name1$" '
    $0~p{cnt=2} 
    --cnt>=0{next} 
    1' file
```

Prints:

```
>name2
textB
>name3
textC
```

Also with `sed` you can use a range match:

```
sed -e '/^>name2$/,/^[^>]/d' file
>name1
textA
>name3
textC
```

Which also works with `awk`:

```
awk '/^>name2$/,/^[^>]/{next} 1' file
# same output
```

Note: If you have `>name2` and `>name20` and/or `200` you should use anchors to assure a complete match. The `^` and `$` used above.

Answer (score 0):

Since this problem seems to arise because there is no record before the first record separator, (i.e. it only applies to line 1), a simple conditional inside your main block fixes it:

```
awk 'BEGIN {RS = ">"; ORS = ""} !/name3/ {if(NR>1){print">"}; print $0}' FILE
```

Answer (score 0):

I added duplicates and extra padding to the test input …

```
 1  
 2  
 3       1  >name1
 4       2  textA
 5       3  >name2
 6       4  textB
 7       5  >name3
 8       6  textC
 9  
10       7  >name1
11       8  textA
12       9  >name2
13      10  textB
14      11  >name3
15      12  textC
16  
17
```

> ```
> mawk 7 ORS= RS='[>]name3[\n\r]+[^\n\r]+[\n\r]*'
> ```

```
 1  >name1
 2  textA
 3  >name2
 4  textB
 5  >name1
 6  textA
 7  >name2
 8  textB
```

…… and output is now gapless